# Where do I find the record pointed to by a naturalization index?

Tags: united-states, new-york-city, naturalization, indexing

I found an image of an [index record](http://www.fold3.com/document.php?doc=17606391&xid=215&p=ma) for a declaration of intent in a New York court, published online as part of the collection [*Alphabetical Index to Declarations of Intention of the U.S. District Court for the Southern District of New York, 1917-1950* on Fold3](https://www.fold3.com/browse/24/hyFUWg4H4). The record only contains a name and two numbers:

```
                         158493
Yurkiewicz, Aleksander
                             299
```

What do the two numbers mean? Is one a page number and the other a record number? Where do I look for the record they point to?

Comment: If you have them, don't hesitate to provide the reference for the index record (image above) that you did located. At least for me, there are circumstance where such references will make the question, possibly the answers more valuable.

Comment: @GeneJ I linked to it in my answer.

Comment: Ha! Next time I'll remember to click!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This record is part of the NARA collection, "NARA M1675. Alphabetical Index to Declarations of Intention of the U.S. District Court for the Southern District of New York, 1917-1950" provided by fold3.

According to [the description](http://www.fold3.com/title_103/naturalization_index_ny_southern_intentions/), the numbers are used to order record copies of the originals from NARA. "The three digit-number on these index cards is the volume number. The other number is the Declaration of Intention number."

For a little more information about this collection and naturalization, see the [fold3 Topic Page](http://www.fold3.com/page/237_indexes_to_naturalization_records/). Included on the topic page are instructions for how to order the Naturalization Records indexed in NARA M1675.

The good news is that it appears you can order these records online! Does seem that in addition to the details from the index, NARA asks you to provide some additional information about the subject such as their approximate date of birth, country of origin and residence details at the time of naturalization. It's not possible for me to tell if this additional information is optional or required.

Comment: Providing the additional information might be a safeguard against transcription errors in the index. Just FYI, the link to The National Archives at New York City : Research in Naturalization Records is  http://www.archives.gov/nyc/finding-aids/naturalization-records.html#copies